# Two out of three drives are in predictive failure on raid-5 - what should I do?

Tags: raid, hard-drive

I've got a problem.
I've got an older Dell PE1800. I noticed in the event manager 1000's of 2094 events: Predictive Failure reported:  Physical Disk 0:1 and on Physical Disk 0:3.
[Open Manage info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi8qc.png)

My question is - if I put in a new disk will it rebuild? I obviously need to replace both disks, but I'm afraid to even pull out one degraded disk. If I lose this server I'm screwed. 
I'd appreciate any help on this! 
Thank you! ~Blaine

Answer (score 7):

Update your back up immediately! Then schedule some down time, replace all three drives, and restore from the backup. There's no reason to take chances.

You can try replacing the drives one at a time, rebuilding after each replacement. But the risk of unexpected downtime is greater and the server will be in a low-performance state for longer. Obviously, update your backup before attempting any such thing.

Comment: Totally agree with gentlemen on top, definitely the best way to go.

Comment: No matter your approach, David's first statement is a must.  Update/have good backups.  With RAID-5 you can only tolerate one disk failure, so if while doing anything with one of those disks the other fails, you're screwed back to re-format and restore backup anyway.

Note.  The error is predictive failure, which may never go bad (I had one begin prediction because of old HDD firmware).  But if the server is that critical, don't wait for one of the disks to really fail.  Backup the server then swap the disk ASAP.

Comment: And once you've taken the drives out of production, you can test them and make a judgment about what you want to do with them. RAID 5 is *not* suitable for applications where an array failure is more than a moderate inconvenience.